# Occurence of a multiple symbol in a string-Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
string='I love #Snorlax he is a beast #op#letsgo'
for item in string.split():
    if item.startswith('#'):
        print(item)
```

The problem with my code is that the output i get is:

```
#Snorlax
#op#letsgo
```

The output should be

```
#Snorlax
#op
```

Comment: No, that is *not* the output of the code you posted. You likely forgot to split `string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
string='I love #Snorlax he is a beast #op#letsgo'
for item in string.split():
    if item.startswith("#"):
        print("#" + item.split("#")[1])
```

Comment: that still gives me `#Snorlax
#op#letsgo`